# Nginx does not work on a domain name but OK on an IP address?

Tags: nginx, archlinux, certbot

Why do I get this page of **This site can’t be reached** but it seems no errors on my terminal?

When I access the server via **IP address** it is fine:

[image]

But with a **domain name**, I get this:

[image]

```
$ sudo systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-04-06 04:19:23 BST; 7h ago
  Process: 7248 ExecStart=/usr/bin/nginx -g pid /run/nginx.pid; error_log stderr; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 7250 (nginx)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─7250 nginx: master process /usr/bin/nginx -g pid /run/nginx.pid; error_log stderr
           └─7251 nginx: worker process                                  

Apr 06 04:19:23 localhost systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Apr 06 04:19:23 localhost systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Apr 06 04:20:00 localhost nginx[7248]: 2017/04/06 04:20:00 [error] 7251#7251: *6 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 183.171
Apr 06 07:14:44 localhost nginx[7248]: 2017/04/06 07:14:44 [error] 7251#7251: *506 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 195.2
Apr 06 08:27:06 localhost nginx[7248]: 2017/04/06 08:27:06 [error] 7251#7251: *574 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 138.2
Apr 06 11:04:58 localhost nginx[7248]: 2017/04/06 11:04:58 [error] 7251#7251: *835 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 183.1
Apr 06 11:17:27 localhost nginx[7248]: 2017/04/06 11:17:27 [error] 7251#7251: *841 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/robots.txt" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 66.249
Apr 06 11:31:40 localhost nginx[7248]: 2017/04/06 11:31:40 [error] 7251#7251: *845 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 183.1
Apr 06 11:32:56 localhost
```

This seems to be the error:

```
*6 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 183.171
```

What does this mean? It is not related to the domain name!

This is part of my config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.co.uk www.example.co.uk;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  example.co.uk www.example.co.uk;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co.uk/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co.uk/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }
}

server {
    listen 8888 ssl;
    server_name  example.co.uk www.example.co.uk;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co.uk/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.co.uk/privkey.pem;

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3838;
    }

}
```

Test the code:

```
$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

It was all working fine before but now suddenly stopped.

Any ideas?

I follow this [guide](https://www.ostechnix.com/install-nginx-mariadb-php-lemp-stack-on-arch-linux-2016/) to install Nginx btw on my Arch Linux.

The steps I take:

```
$ sudo pacman -Syu
$ sudo pacman -S nginx
```

Start Nginx service and enable it to start at boot using commands:

```
$ sudo systemctl start nginx
$ sudo systemctl enable nginx
```

**EDIT:**

I now have uninstalled Ngnix and reinstalled it, but it is not working anymore even on a fresh start without any config to the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. What I get is **This site can’t be reached' on browsers**.

Why!??

I checked with `netstat` and I can see that the port 80 is in the list:

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5361/mongod         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3666/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10701/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3667/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3838            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32434/shiny-server  
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN      3666/systemd-resolv 
tcp6       0      0 :::3030                 :::*                    LISTEN      17325/node /usr/loc 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      3667/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      17325/node /usr/loc 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*                           3666/systemd-resolv 
udp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                                3666/systemd-resolv
```

**EDIT 2:**

I created an access log. But I don't see any major errors there:

```
$ more -f /etc/nginx/logs/access.log
183.171.92.177 - - [06/Apr/2017:12:38:09 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/57.0.2987.98 Chrome/57.0.2987.98 Safari/537.36" "-"
183.171.92.177 - - [06/Apr/2017:12:38:09 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/57.0.2987.98 Chrome/57.0.2987.98 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Comment: Hey, were you able to find out & resolve this problem? I am also facing the same issue!

Comment: I have the same problem it's working when I make a request on IP but not on domain

Answer (score 0):

Find what is going on from the Nginx access logs! Before checking it, ensure that you are logging enough. You can use the following log_format.

```
log_format main '$host - $remote_addr - $remote_user - [$time_local] - $document_root - $document_uri - $request - $status - $body_bytes_sent - $http_referer';
```

Restart your Nginx service and make a few requests. You need to find out if the request is even reaching the server. Access logs should give you a clear indication of what's going on.

Comment: it happens only when the domain name is used but OK on IP address. See my edited version above. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have a dns server in place, to send a request to your server with the specified domain name, you need to add an entry in the /etc/hosts (this path depends on your local machine system) file of the client machine.
You need to add the following line in that file,like so:

```
sudo nano /private/etc/hosts
```

...and:

```
# The client /etc/hosts file

<ip-of-your-server>   www.yourdomainname.com
```